# Find enclosed in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> Please **find enclosed** a cheque for £100.

What does it mean?
[Oxford Learners Dictionaries: enclosed](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enclosed?q=enclosed)

Answer (score 1):

It means that the cheque is in the envelope with the letter. Nowadays we would probably write "I enclose a cheque for £100", but "please find enclosed..." is the old-fashioned polite way to say it.

Comment: People write 'please find attached...' in emails even nowadays.